# Run datagrid filter with only one character .. or not?

Tags: filter, data-tables

Imagine that you are using a wildcard filter '%XXX%' which runs automatically after one second and search across 10K rows datatable with 10+ fields.

From the point of view of infrastructure resources optimization, it seems inefficient to filter a single character because it will send back almost everything in almost any case.

What do you think about the user experience? Does the user expects that the filtering starts with a single character, knowing that most users will probably type 2+ characters anyway? Will it seem strange that the filter does not run when a key is pressed?

Comment: Is a single character a valid and meaningful search in your use case?

Comment: I have no idea, it's a cloud service with thousands of use cases, different accounts, various usages. No way to know. Intuitively I would find it strange to filter multiple fields on a single char, but it may eventually happen as Travis pointed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many use cases, a single character filter/search is valid. The best way to simplify this is to run the filter when the user starts typing. Wait for a length of time after each key press. If another key is pressed, restart the counter. Perhaps a length between .5 seconds and 1 second would be best.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion that a single char may be a valid request. Of course, already have 750ms timeout on key press events :)